# OpenCV 3 with Python 3 on Windows separate HD

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I want openCV and Python to be installed to and run on a second HD (E: in this case). Things seemed OK after following the instructions provided in https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
image = cv2.imread("clouds.jpg")
function OK, but
image = cv2.imread("clouds.jpg")
```

results in this:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds", image) 
    cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:304:
    error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow"
```

Any idea of how to get cv2 to look for projects\opencv.... on E:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `traceback` tells the image is empty or the path is incorrect. Double check the image name and it's path, if any, is correct in `imread()`.

Example:

- `cv2.imread('E:/path/to/image.jpg')` or
- `cv2.imread('E:\\path\\to\\image.jpg')`

Hope this help.

Comment: thewaywewere Thanks for response.  That was all that was needed! I assumed that the path variable would take care of finding things.

Comment: Leonardo Chirivì.  Thanks for the editing for improving my post.  I'm extremely new to using this website and need all the help I can get!

Comment: @user3338092 You are welcome. If the answer to your question help, could you 'tick` the answer at the left to close?

Comment: I'm a noobie(?) and don't understand "'tick' the answer at the left".

Comment: @user3338092 you have accepted my answer so the green tick showed! If the answer fully helped to solve your problem, please give me a vote up by clicking the up arrow and the positive count number will increase by one. Thanks.